# Displaying Indian Rupees currency in my Vb.net Application

Tags: vb.net, currency

I created and Vb.net application in which i've used ***Indian rupees symbol***. I inserted it from my laptop in which **ruppee symbol** is printed on num 4 and it is visible in my laptop. But when i deploy this application to my customer's system it show a box instead.

Help me how to Figure it out...

Comment: check the font installed in the client machine ?

Comment: try using this font in the client machine. [Get font here](https://phaven-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/files/unknown_part/asset/815419/dNpzdPaLI03ZY8FImtqWGGa0CTs/Rupee.ttf)

Comment: Use `charmap.exe` to determine whether your UI element's font actually has a symbol for the Unicode character code you're using.

Comment: @Mels it doesnot show in charmap.exe

Comment: @FarhanMukadam i have already tried but it doesnot have any alphabets

Answer (score 0):

I konw you are looking for desktop app below is the solution for web but will give you some idea

[Web Solution here](http://daxserver.com/how-to-display-indian-rupee-symbol-in-websites/)

[Word Solution here](http://daxserver.com/how-to-type-indian-rupee-symbol-in-ms-word/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cost As Double = 2524000
Dim str As String = cost.ToString("C", New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("hi-IN"))
str = str.Remove(0, 3)
Label1.Text = str
```